# RuntimeError: The specified pointer resides on host memory and is not registered with any CUDA device

Tags: pytorch

My code is here

```
                with cp.cuda.Device(cp_device):
                    candidates = cp.zeros((point_idxs.shape[0], num_rots, 3), cp.float32)

                    block_size = (point_idxs.shape[0] + 512 - 1) // 512
                    rot_voting_kernel(
                        (block_size, 1, 1),
                        (512, 1, 1),
                        (
                            cp.asarray(pc), cp.asarray(preds_tr[0].cpu().numpy()), cp.asarray(direction[0].cpu().numpy()), candidates, cp.asarray(point_idxs).astype(cp.int32), cp.asarray(corners[0]).astype(cp.float32), cp.float32(cfg.res), 
                            point_idxs.shape[0], num_rots, grid_obj.shape[0], grid_obj.shape[1], grid_obj.shape[2]
                        )
                    )
                    sph_cp = torch.tensor(sphere_pts.T, dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
                    start = np.arange(0, point_idxs.shape[0] * num_rots, num_rots)
                    np.random.shuffle(start)
                    sub_sample_idx = (start[:10000, None] + np.arange(num_rots)[None]).reshape(-1)
                    candidates = torch.as_tensor(candidates, device='cuda').reshape(-1, 3)
                    candidates = candidates[torch.LongTensor(sub_sample_idx).cuda()]
                    cos = candidates.mm(sph_cp)
                    counts = torch.sum(cos > np.cos(angle_tol / 180 * np.pi), 0).cpu().numpy()
                best_dir = np.array(sphere_pts[np.argmax(counts)])
```

when i run the code in wsl, i got this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nocs/inference.py", line 298, in <module>
    candidates = torch.as_tensor(candidates, device='cuda').reshape(-1, 3)
RuntimeError: The specified pointer resides on host memory and is not registered with any CUDA device.
```

how to solve the question?

i tried google but didn't get any idea.